# How do I write a median filter in java?

Tags: java, python, filtering

I have the following median filter in python that I need to convert to java as part of my project. Problem is, I have no understanding of how this is supposed to work.

```
def medfilt (x, k):
    """Apply a length-k median filter to a 1D array x.
    Boundaries are extended by repeating endpoints.
    """
    assert k % 2 == 1, "Median filter length must be odd."
    assert x.ndim == 1, "Input must be one-dimensional."
    k2 = (k - 1) // 2
    y = np.zeros ((len (x), k), dtype=x.dtype)
    y[:,k2] = x
    for i in range (k2):
        j = k2 - i
        y[j:,i] = x[:-j]
        y[:j,i] = x[0]
        y[:-j,-(i+1)] = x[j:]
        y[-j:,-(i+1)] = x[-1]fi
    return np.median (y, axis=1)
```

any help / resources would be appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: I understand what the alg is doing, but not sure how to best convert the range stuff to java:

```
for i in range (k2):
        j = k2 - i
        y[j:,i] = x[:-j]
        y[:j,i] = x[0]
        y[:-j,-(i+1)] = x[j:]
        y[-j:,-(i+1)] = x[-1]fi
```

Comment: `Problem is, I have no understanding of how this is supposed to work.` Well that'll make things difficult..

Comment: Well, Wikipedia is usually a good start. Did you try that? How did that work out?

Comment: Clearly if I posted this I still don't understand it. But thanks for the condescension.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is calling numpy methods. For the median method call, look here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html. For learning how to use numpy to understand better how this method works, here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/.

A 'median filter', as I know it, is used in signal processing to do noise reduction. This example seems to be working with some kind of scientific dataset, although I'm not sure with just this one code piece. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) would be a good place to start, and [scipy even has such a method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html). This just seems to be a special implementation of a median filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting median filter, and I have to admit I cannot think of its use. The vectorisation performed there does not seem to be very beneficial from the performance point of view, and thus the actual median finding could be done within the loop.

Just to see what the loop does, let us assume k=7. Then k2 = 3, and the loop is run three times (two will suffice to show what happens):

```
i = 0
j = 3
# fill in row 0
# shift the x vector right by three and fill the beginning with the first element
y[3:,0] = x[:-3]
y[:3,0] = x[0] 
# fill in the last row (-1), i.e. row 6
# shift the x vector left by 3 and fill the end by the last element   
y[:-3,-1] = x[3:]
y[-3:,-1] = x[-1]

i = 1
j = 2
# fill in row 1
# shift the x vector right by 2 and fill the beginning with the first element
y[2:,0] = x[:-2]
y[:2,0] = x[0] 
# fill in the second last row (-2), i.e. row 5
# shift the x vector left by 2 and fill the end by the last element   
y[:-2,-1] = x[2:]
y[-2:,-1] = x[-1]

...
```

(I would like to tell the original writer of the code that for loops are not expensive, and python is about legibility. Two loops would have been much easier to read, and this algorithm can be made much faster in other ways.)

Anyway, the desired array is:

```
x0 x0 x0 x0 x1 x2 x3 ...          x(n-4)
x0 x0 x0 x1 x2 x3 ...             x(n-3)
x0 x0 x1 x2 x3 ...                x(n-2)
x0 x1 x2 x3 ...                   x(n-1)
x1 x2 x3 ...               x(n-1) x(n-1)
x2 x3 x4 ...        x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1)
x3 x4 x5 ... x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1)
```

and the result vector is the median of each of these.

To my eye it seems that there is a lot of room for improvement in the algorithm regardless of the language. In any case it is not very useful to calculate the array and then take the median. One would be better off just creating a vector y for each loop.

(As a BTW, the code could be written in million ways to be more legible, for example:

```
n = len(x)
k2 = k / 2
y = np.empty(n + 2 * k2)
m = np.empty(k)
for i in range(k):
    y[:i] = x[0]
    y[i, i:n+i] = x
    y[n+i:] = x[-1]
    m[i] = median(y[k2:-k2])
return m
```

But that's another story.)

In this case it would be enough to calculate the available medians for the full vector x (that will give x - (k-1)/2 samples). Then the different edge paddings can be calculated separately, i.e.:

```
median( x0 x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5)
median( x0 x0 x0 x1 x2 x3 x4)
median( x0 x0 x0 x0 x1 x2 x3) = x0
median( x0 x0 x0 x0 x0 x1 x2) = x0
median( x0 x0 x0 x0 x0 x0 x1) = x0

median( x(n-6) x(n-5) x(n-2) x(n-3) x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) )
median( x(n-5) x(n-4) x(n-3) x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) )
median( x(n-4) x(n-3) x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) ) = x(n-1)
median( x(n-3) x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) ) = x(n-1)
median( x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) ) = x(n-1)
```

So, actually you can get all the information this algorithm gives just by simply taking the median of a vector:

```
x0 x0 x0 x0 x1 x2 ... x(n-2) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1) x(n-1)
```

The amount of padding at each end is (k-1)/2 for a k-point median filter. It seems that the algorithm is a bit silly or I have missed something.